# Question regarding diagonalization and eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My professor gave us a question and I would like some help in it.
The problem goes as follows:
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation represented by:
$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2-x_3,x_1+3x_2+x_3,-3x_1+x_2-x_3)$

a) Find the standard matrix $A$ for T.

b) Show that $A$  is diagonalizable.

c) Compute $A^3$.

d) Find a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the matrix $A$ relative to $B$ is diagonal.

I'm not sure what part d) is asking of me. Could anyone explain it in simpler terms?

Answer (score 0):

Given a *diagonalizable* linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, you can always find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors of $T$. Your job here is to find eigenvectors of $T$ and use them as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The point of part d) is that $A = BDB^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal and $B$ contains eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues on the diagonal of $D$.

Comment: So D is the basis whose values on the main diagonal are the eigenvalues of T?

Comment: Your  sentence: "you can always find a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ of eigenvectors of $T$" isn't correct. It's true only for a diagonalizable linear transformation.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Do you mind explaining why is it that we can use the eigenvalues of the transform T to get a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Compute the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and you find that the eigenvalues are distinct. Conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable and find a basis of eigenvectors of $A$ in which $T$ is diagonal.@OscarFlores

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Yes, yes, thank you. In my head I seem to be constantly conflating "can be split into eigenspaces" with "has a basis of eigenvectors."

Comment: You're welcome@Neal